# scrollable tab (swipe) with API 8

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to use the code template provided by android in eclipse and I set my min SDK to API 8. I tried to choose the "blank activity with scrollable tab" for using the swipe feature but it wouldn't let me continue and complaining that this code template support version 11 and more.

However, I thought that's why the support library of version 4 is! To support Api 4 and above.

Am I missing the point here or is there something I need to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the android.support.v7 compatibility libraries (which work together with the v4 libraries).

When you create the project in eclipse set the minimum API version to 11 but once the project is created, edit AndroidManifest.xml to set minSDKVersion to 8.

From time to time when building the project, eclipse may complain about min SDK version being required for certain things - in this case just Clean the project and it will build without problems.

Comment: Thank you. That's a great idea. But the android website says that v7 work for min api 11.plus why would I need V7 in the first place? V4 should be needed only

Comment: @Snake : Sorry, I should have clarified the reason. The v7 support library is the most recent and adds Action Bar capability (as well as other stuff) which the v4 library didn't have. If you add v7 support you'll get the latest compatibility for projects with min API 7 and onwards.

Comment: Thank you  guess I will just add those 2 libs for every project I make

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten it to work using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and ViewTabPager. Look into those